# Get vertical offset in scrollviewer for different ListViewItems in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, offset, scrollviewer

I have ListView with 5 items which have different height. I need to obtain vertical offset for item 3, for example. What should I do?
Here is some code:

```
var currentOffset = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
var thirdItem = listView.ItemsPanelRoot.Children[2];

var thirdItemOffset = // ?? what should I do here to get offset??
```